# How to resolve DNS name to IP if internet connection has a manual proxy settings?

Tags: java, android, dns

I want to resolve DNS name to the appropriate IP by using following code:

```
   try 
   {
       InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
       byte []addr = address.getAddress();
   }
   catch(UnknownHostException e) 
   {       
   }
```

This code works perfectly if I use WiFi connection without Proxy settings.
If I use WiFi connection which has Proxy settings I get **UnknownHostException** 
In the same time I can browse the "www.google.com" while being behind the proxy.

Please explain me why this happens and how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using an HTTP proxy server, the DNS lookup of domain names of all web requests is handled by the proxy.

More than likely, when you are on a network that requires a proxy server, the network blocks all other internet traffic not going through the proxy, including access to DNS port 53.  Hence, only web browser and apps using HTTP libraries works.  Apps using socket libraries typically fail to work.

I suspect that your network requiring a proxy setting is at work while your network without a proxy setting is at home. Enterprise firewall configurations with such proxies, such as those in the work place, typically restrain network traffic to "web only".